# Kernel of Gysin map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, pullback

Let $X$ be a variety, let $D_1$, $D_2$ be linearly equivalent effective Cartier divisors on $X$ and let $\varphi_i\colon A_{k+1}(X)\to A_{k}(D_i)$ be the Gysin homomorphism. Is $\ker(\varphi_1) = \ker(\varphi_2)$?

Comment: No. For an example, you can take $X$ to be a suitable elliptic surface (e.g. $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up along the base locus of a general pencil of elliptic curves), $D_1$ a general smooth fibre and $D_2$ a singular fibre.